# Odoo11 EE How removing signature advertisement

Tags: javascript, odoo-11, qweb, odoo-enterprise

I'm trying to inherit website_sign.thank_you_dialog but this has no id. I would like to delete the advertisement that appears in the pop up when completing the signatures.

**Odoo 11 EE**

**/static/src/js/remove_ad_signature.js**

```js
odoo.define('my_module.signature_request_template', function(require) { 
    'use strict'

    var ajax = require("web.ajax");
    var core = require("web.core");
    var qweb = core.qweb;
    var document_signing = require("website_sign.document_signing");

    ajax.loadXML("/my_module/static/src/xml/remove_ad_signature.xml", qweb).then(function () {
    document_signing.initDocumentToSign();
    });
})
```

**/static/src/xml/remove_ad_signature.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <templates id="remove_ad_signature" xml:space="preserve">
     <t t-extend="website_sign.thank_you_dialog">
         <t t-jquery="div.o_promote_esign" t-operation="replace">
             <div class="o_promote_esign">
                 <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>                 
             </div>                                       
         </t>                                             
     </t>                                                 

 </templates>
```

I see AAAAAA on the modal but return this error **Sorry, an error occured, please try to fill the document again.**
[image]

Comment: It will appear(the error popup) after your sign operation perform?  if your thankyou popup and within that this error generate? if yes then kindly check your sign up flow there have some missing things to work, this is the default odoo error raise while some issue in signature performs.

Comment: Hi Dipen Shah, the error is given by my changes, what I want to delete / modify is the ad popup that appears after signing

Comment: you can check this error you can find the controller with sign/sign where it calls it will not return the appropriate data. so result of this change you face this warning.

Comment: I checked the error but it doesn't seem to come from the controller, the error lies in the template / js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself
add in static/src/js/remove_signature_ad.js

```js
odoo.define("agreements_esign.remove_signature_ad_button", function (require) {
  "use strict"

  var core = require("web.core")
  var document_signing = require("website_sign.document_signing")
  var _t = core._t

  var NoPubThankYouDialog = document_signing.ThankYouDialog.extend({
    template: "website_sign.no_pub_thank_you_dialog",

    init: function (parent, options) {
      options = options || {}
      if (!options.buttons) {
        options.buttons = [{ text: _t("Close"), close: true }]
      }

      this._super(parent, options)
    }
    })

  document_signing.SignableDocument.include({
    get_thankyoudialog_class: function () {
      return NoPubThankYouDialog
    },
  })
})
```

Now I see this

[image]